# First button click not getting fired - Jquery Delegates

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I dynamically loaded a template on the webpage and I am intended to do some operation with the `id` of the button. I have used the same name for all the buttons on the template. And I used Jquery delegates to alert the `id` upon the button click.

But the issue is that the button click event is not getting fired for the first button click and is working for the subsequent clicks. Once I reload the page, the same issue again. How to actually stop this. I am attaching the Jquery code below.

### JQUERY

```
 $("table").on("click", "button",function(event) {
    $("[name='DEL_BTN']").on('click',function(event){
        event.stopPropagation(); 
        alert(this.id)})
      });
```

### HTML

```
<!-- LAYOUT OPTIONS -->
  <div class="container">
    <table class="table shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded" id="TABLE_CONTAINER">

    </table>
  </div>
```

### HANDLEBARS_TEMPLATE

```
<thead class="thead-dark">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">NAME</th>
    <th scope="col">EMAIL</th>
    <th scope="col">DOB</th>
    <th scope="col">DEPT</th>
    <th scope="col">GENDER</th>
    <th scope="col">AGE</th>
    <th scope="col"></th>
    <th scope="col"></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    {{#each ALL_RECORDS}}
  <tr>
    <td scope="row">{{this.name}}</td>
    <td scope="row">{{this.eMail}}</td>
    <td scope="row">{{this.DOB}}</td>
    <td scope="row">{{this.dept}}</td>
    <td scope="row">{{this.gender}}</td>
    <td scope="row">{{this.age}}</td>
    <th scope="row" style="text-align: center"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="EDIT_BTN" id="{{this._id}}">EDIT</button></th>
    <th scope="row" style="text-align: center"><button class="btn btn-danger"  type="button" name="DEL_BTN" id="{{this._id}}">DELETE</button></th>   
  </tr>
  {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

Also can you please explain the reason for why it is happening. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: You need to show the associated HTML.

Comment: It is because this onclick listener `$("[name='DEL_BTN']")` is only added after you have first clicked this `$("table")` event. Remove the outer `$("table")` click listener for it to work.

Comment: @gforce301 I've updated the HTML and Template section. Please have a look. Thank you.

Comment: @GaryThomas. Thank you for your comment. But once I remove the $("table"), I was not at all able to fire the button clicks as I was loading the dynamic template.

Comment: You could try to create a on load Event for the button, and then add the on click event to it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because of how you are adding the click event listener into your button. You are adding the event inside another handler [of the first click], therefore, the button click with the alert handler within it (`$("[name='DEL_BTN']")`) will be registered only after you clicked the first time.

Check the comments bellow.

```
 $("table").on("click", "button", function(event) {

    // Wen you click first time it will register the next click:

    $("[name='DEL_BTN']").on('click',function(event){

       // Then on the second click, this event is now defined,
       // that's why it runs only after the first click

        event.stopPropagation(); 
        alert(this.id)})
      });
  });
```

So in order to solve this, you have to declare it on the first handler only once like bellow:

```
$("table").on("click", "[name='DEL_BTN']", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation(); 
    alert(this.id)})
});
```

> **Note on Handlebars.js:** Make sure you are declaring this events after compiling the template with `handlebars`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Thanks for the crystal clear explanation.